# find and replace full line in unix script

Tags: shell

I have file called `praveen.pl`. This script contains many lines, one of which is:

```
$input_store_nbr = "00100";
```

What ever number is inside the `"nnnnn"` will be changed by manual testers as per their input.  So, I want to find this line and change this `"nnnnn"` per my input.

For example if my input is `10000` this line in `praveen.pl` should change to

```
$input_store_nbr = "10000";
```

Next time if I want to change it to `20000` this line should change to

```
$input_store_nbr = "20000";
```

I am trying to automate this store number edit in `praveen.pl` file.

Comment: You can declare the value at the top of the script, then assign it to $input_store_nbr.

Comment: Can you just make that variable be a parameter you pass to the script instead of one that's hard coded within the script?

Comment: To add to Eric's comment, you might want to take a look at Perl's ARGV. Details here : https://perlmaven.com/argv-in-perl

Comment: I wouldn't consider automated editing of code to be good practice. I would also suggest that if it's something you think you need to do you need to rethink the design.

Comment: same script is executed more than 1000 scenario ..but before running this script we should change the store number according to scenerio.

Comment: same script is executed more than 1000 scenario ..but before running this script we should change the store number according to scenerio that is why i am trying to automate this.

Comment: Sure, but if you have something that is changing the code then running it, you could just run it and pass the new value on the command line, and have this script get it from ARGV instead of having to rewrite the value, e.g., you would run it as `perl praveen.pl 10000` instead of just `perl praveen.pl` after changing the code

Comment: Agree with @EricRenouf. If you're still for it, just use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: This script doesn't belong to me.I am automating front end using selenium and submitting a job using selenium in webpage i have to edit this script in unix and execute it.My only option is to edit that store number so kindly help me with sed or awk to match this exact pattern and replace it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply must modify this is script, and yet cannot modify it to accept a command line parameter for some strange reason you could try the following:

```
new_val=5000
sed -e "s/\$input_store_nbr = \"[0-9]+\";/\$input_store_nbr = \"$new_val\";/" src_file > tmp_file
mv tmp_file src_file
```

or if you have a `sed` that supports it (like GNU or BSD with an argument) you could use the `-i` flag to `sed` and not need the (explicit) temporary file.

I still think you'd be better of modifying the source script one time though (since are already modifying it) to do something like:

```
$input_store_nbr = $ARGV[0];
```

then invoking it with the new number as the first command line argument, as you would have passed to the `sed` script to rewrite the file.

Comment: Thanks eric .I got similar sed command which worked for me.Thank you so much for all.